# Echo HTML in Command Prompt to file loop

Tags: html, text, for-loop, cmd, echo

I have been searching for hours now and didn't find a solution yet.

**This is the whole command with a loop:**

```
for /L %a in (1, 1, 3) do call echo ^<center^> >indeex%a.html
```

**Output results (**Without any text in them***):*

indeex1.html

indeex2.html

indeex3.html

**I tried the other way with quotes, it worked but it included the quotes in the output files.(without carrot signs)**

```
for /L %a in (1, 1, 3) do call echo "<center>" >indeex%a.html
```

When I try the same code with carrot signs but without loops, it actually works.

```
echo ^<center^> >file.html
```

My question is how to make it work with a loop?
Because I need to make 100 files with the same HTML code in them.

Comment: What do you want it to output?

Comment: I need to make 100 files with the same HTML code in them. But the problem is that it outputs quotes if i use quotes in echo command, when i use carrot signs before '<' '>' symbols it outputs a blank file ( when i use loops) but without loops it works.

Comment: Do you need ^ in your file?

Comment: No I don't need ^ in file. When I work with a single file:
**echo ^<center^> >file.html**
the final result in the file.html (output) is:
**<center>** and it works, but it doesn't with the loops..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /L %a in (1, 1, 3) do echo ^<center^> >indeex%a.html
```

Comment: Could you tell me where was my problem?

Comment: I got rid of the "call".